# How to delete an event with the Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

I have created 2 same events on a venue, and I'd like to delete one of them.

But the events are not displayed and I can't delete them.

Is it possible to use the Foursquare API to do it ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't delete events via the API. Are you the venue manager or know the manager? The best way to remove events is directly through the event management tools Foursquare currently provides.